# DbUnit execuing SQL statement returns: "SQL statement would generate a row count"

Tags: exception, jdbc, hana, dbunit

I have an SQL statement which works fine.
It is a select statement and returns rows as expected.

Why do I get the error: 
`org.dbunit.dataset.DataSetException: com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.JDBCDriverException: SAP DBTech JDBC: SQL statement would generate a row count.`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be solved by removing the semi-colon at the end of the SQL Statement.